# Azure event hub events not appearing

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

We are using azure event hub for sending commands which are processed by backend workers.

code to send events is simple

```
_events=EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(
             (new Microsoft.ServiceBus.ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EventHubConnectionString"].ConnectionString) { TransportType = Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.TransportType.Amqp,OperationTimeout=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180) }).ToString(),
              ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EventHubName"]
await _events.SendEventAsync(command);
```

however we are now seeing issues where some commands do not appear immediately in service bus explorer event hub , also i see some logs in the service bus explorer log which say

```
<12:11:21> InnerException: The operation was canceled.
<12:11:25> Exception: The AMQP object link16344 is aborted. TrackingId:N/A, 
Reference:3b79459a64f64e52a689fd97dfb9cc71_G31, Timestamp:8/4/2017 6:41:25 AM
```

I suspect this has something to do with next events not appearing.

How do i debug/troubleshoot?

Comment: You do not get any client side exceptions? Is there a reason for not awaiting the call to `SendEventAsync` ? It might hide exceptions due to that. Can you give a larger picture of the code?

Comment: apologies, we do use await.post edited. no client side exceptions.message appears to be sent successfully

Comment: Do you have a retry policy in place? See https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/47 and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c6247c42-7422-402b-b0b5-d02c452bd609/event-hubs-sporadic-exceptions?forum=servbus